# How to add a dependency to an object file in cmake

Tags: cmake

So I'm trying to convert a make-based project to cmake, and having trouble wrapping my head around how it works.  I've figured out how to get custom commands to generate a header file, and how to compile source file for the target executable, but I can't seem to link them together -- I can't figure out how to trigger the custom command to generate the header file.  Here's a trivial example of what I'm trying to do:

CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_executable(test test.c)
add_custom_command(OUTPUT foo.h
  COMMAND echo "/* test */" > foo.h
)
```

test.c:

```
#include "foo.h"
int main() { return 0; }
```

However, when I run cmake and make, it gives me:

```
/home/cdodd/test/test.c:1:17: fatal error: foo.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

It can't seem to figure out that it needs to create foo.h first before compiling test.c.  With make I'd just add a dependency; how do I do that with cmake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the generated file `foo.h` to the executable target as a dependency:

```
add_executable(testexe test.c foo.h)
```

This will make CMake add a file level dependency of the target `testexe` to the file `foo.h` in the generated build system.

Comment: This seems to work, but is it guarenteed to always generate the header file before trying to compile the file that uses it?

Comment: The solution guarantees that the header file is generated, if it does not yet exist.

Comment: In my opinion, this is not exactly correct. The target `testexe` really depends only on `test.o` which, in turn, depends on `test.c` and `foo.h`. Especially in multi thread builds it can happen that it is attempted to build `test.o` before `foo.h`.